# How to get data from multiple databases in Same Server using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

There are multiple databases in the same Server (SQL Server). My requirement is when a GUID is given as input in a C# Windows Forms Application, I have to query for the details corresponding to that GUID across all the databases and show it in the application. Table Name is same in all the databases. That is, if the details are not found in one database, then I have to check in another database(within the same server) and have to iterate through a loop. But this hits performance as there are more than 10 databases. So, is there a way to fetch details in an efficient manner? I have searched extensively but could not find any solution

I don't have permissions to create anything like a View in the database Server. I have permission to use only select queries to fetch data from any of those databases

Please let me know if anymore details are required

Comment: You do know you can use a three part name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information you have provided, it sounds like you have many DBs to look into but, you only need to loop through them until you find what you need, or until you run out of Database to look into. Meaning that if you find what you need in DB #3, you shouldn't go into DB #4, #5, and so on. Hopefully this will help. To me this *great* on performance in the sense that you don't query DBs you don't need to.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string textThatWouldBeInATextBoxOnTheUserInterface = "1234,4567,789";//lets pretend this is the textbox value entered by the user
        string[] GUIDs = textThatWouldBeInATextBoxOnTheUserInterface.Split(',').ToArray();//split that string into a string[]
        List<string> listOfResults = new List<string>();//create something to hold your results

        //iterate through each string
        foreach (string item in GUIDs)
        {
            listOfResults.Add(getTheData(item));//add results to your list
        }
    }

    private string getTheData(string incomingID)
    {
        List<string> dbConnStrings = new List<string>();
        dbConnStrings.Add(@"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=ServerName\Schema;Database=dbName1;User Id=uid;Password=pwd;");
        dbConnStrings.Add(@"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=ServerName\Schema;Database=dbName2;User Id=uid;Password=pwd;");
        string sqlQuery = "select whatever from TheTable where MyRestriction = " + incomingID;
        bool HaveYouFoundItYet = false;
        int TrackMyPositionInTheList = 0;
        string queryResults = string.Empty;

        while (!HaveYouFoundItYet && TrackMyPositionInTheList < dbConnStrings.Count)//while you haven't found it and there are still DBs to look into
        {
            using (OleDbConnection currentConnection = new OleDbConnection(dbConnStrings[TrackMyPositionInTheList]))//look into the DB determined by the PositionTracker
            {
                currentConnection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, currentConnection);

                if (command.ExecuteScalar() != null)//if you found what you're looking for
                {
                    queryResults = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();//do whatever with your pulled data
                    HaveYouFoundItYet = true;//make the while loop stop
                }
                else
                {
                    TrackMyPositionInTheList++;//Lets increment the PositionTracker by 1 and look again.
                }
            }
        }

        return queryResults;
    }
```

*edit*
here's a possibly faster way

```
    /// <summary>
    /// this way should be faster than the previous one
    /// because we won't connect to the same DB more than once.
    /// </summary>
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //string textThatWouldBeInATextBoxOnTheUserInterface = "30439,30447,32273,32270";//lets pretend this is the textbox value entered by the user
        string textThatWouldBeInATextBoxOnTheUserInterface = "30439,30447,32273";//lets pretend this is the textbox value entered by the user

        Dictionary<string, string> DictionaryOfResults = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        DictionaryOfResults = getTheDataLoopingThroughIDs(textThatWouldBeInATextBoxOnTheUserInterface);
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> getTheDataLoopingThroughIDs(string incomingIDs)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> incomingIDsTracker = new Dictionary<string, string>();//something to keep track of the incomingIDs
        foreach (string item in incomingIDs.Replace(" ", "").Split(','))
        {
            incomingIDsTracker.Add(item, null);//add all the ids(keys) to the dictionary, and give them a null value to start
        }

        //lets build the list of DBs we can connect to
        List<string> dbConnStrings = new List<string>();
        dbConnStrings.Add(@"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=Server\Schema;Database=dbName1;User Id=uid;Password=pwd;");
        dbConnStrings.Add(@"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=Server\Schema;Database=dbName2;User Id=uid;Password=pwd;");
        int TrackMyPositionInTheList = 0;//keep track of how many DBs you connected to

        while (incomingIDsTracker.ContainsValue(null) && TrackMyPositionInTheList < dbConnStrings.Count)//while there are values we haven't found yet, and while there are still DBs to connect to
        {
            using (OleDbConnection currentConnection = new OleDbConnection(dbConnStrings[TrackMyPositionInTheList]))//look into the DB determined by the PositionTracker
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> tempdict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                tempdict = incomingIDsTracker.Where(p => p.Value == null).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);//make a temp dictionary of only the keys with null values
                string idstolookfor = string.Join(",", tempdict.Keys);//make that into a comma separated list that we can use in our sql query
                string sqlQuery = "select dialid, docid from dial where dialid in (" + idstolookfor + ")";
                currentConnection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, currentConnection);

                if (command.ExecuteScalar() != null)//if you found something
                {
                    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        incomingIDsTracker[reader["DialId"].ToString()] = reader["docid"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                TrackMyPositionInTheList++;//Lets increment the PositionTracker by 1 and look again.
            }
        }
        return incomingIDsTracker;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks blaze. I will try this option. And if there are more than 1 guid's, should we loop this process for all the guids?

Comment: Krishna, why would there be more than 1 GUID? Are you saying the use may provide more than 1 GUID in the textbox, or are you saying the DB result would contain more than 1 record? If the user is to supply more than 1 GUID, then yes you'll want to loop through them. Let me see if I can update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much blaze. I have implemented as you suggested. Though its not that faster, I was able to implement it in my application. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await with CancellationToken.
Initiate multiple simultaneous asynchronous requests and when one returns the result cancel the others.
For example:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string[] servers = new[] { "server1", "server2", "server3" };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.button1.Enabled = false;
            string guid = this.textBox1.Text;

            var _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = _cts.Token;
            var tasks = new List<Task<Data>>();

            foreach (var server in this.servers)
            {
                tasks.Add(this.GetData(guid, server, token));
            }

            var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks.ToArray());
            _cts.Cancel();
            var data = completedTask.Result;
            this.button1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private  async Task<Data> GetData(string guid, string database, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                //Simulate long running task
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(r.Next(1, 2)), cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Operation was cancelled");
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

            return new Data();
        }

    private class Data
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a three part name

```
Select col from db1.dbo.table2 where guid = 'xxx'
union  
Select col from db2.dbo.table2 where guid = 'xxx'
```

Comment: Yes but there are more than 2 databases. In fact, there are more than 10 databases. So should I write union number of times?

Comment: Uh, yes.  And I bet your table names are different.  You will need to adapt.